# Guide a newbie: PHP 7 warning: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, wordpress

After upgrading to PHP 7 I get the following error message in a really old WP theme. Unfortunately changing the theme is not an option right now, so I have to try to find a fix. I can kind of read PHP, but have a hard time writing it on my own, so I'd love some pointers on how to change this.

The Error message:

`Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

The code that needs to implement Countable

```
        if (defined('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE') && WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE) {
            $settings = $this['option']->get('warp_theme_options', array());
        } else {
            $settings = ($file = $this['path']->path('template:config')) ? file_get_contents($file) : array();
        }

        // set config or load defaults
        if (count($settings)) {
            $this->config = $this['data']->create($settings);
        } else {
            $this->config = $this['data']->create(file_get_contents($this['path']->path('template:config.default')));
        }
```

From trying to read up on this I think the error is that **count** no longer allows Null? But how would I change the code if statement above to work then?

Comment: What does `$settings` look like? That's the parameter that needs to implement Countable.

Comment: I can't seem to format code-block in the comment. I have updated the answer instead. Thank you for any pointers!

Comment: You just need to keep debugging this. What does `$file` contain? what does `$this['option']->get('warp_theme_options', array());` return? Unless someone is familiar with your wordpress version and theme, there's no real way to know all this. Keep checking what the values are by debugging, and check with PHP documentation to see if it implements Countable.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the answer. I do appreciate it.